# mongoid destroy_all followed with count result in cached result

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I using MongoId reading through the given answer for the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112420/mongoid-query-caching) I understood Mongoid

does not cache any query

Now when running the below query

> PartPriceRecord.destroy_all
>
> PartPriceRecord.count()
>      ==> 31721

How that is possible i just delete all the record ,this get me a feel mongo is caching certain query

In my mongoid query log I can see for every delete two query operating

```
MONGODB (0ms) decisiv_staging['system.indexes'].insert([{:name=>"part_number_1", :ns=>"decisiv_staging.part_price_records", :key=>{"part_number"=>1}, :unique=>true}])
MONGODB (0ms) decisiv_staging['part_price_records'].remove({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('4fa39b35edd7f4306b0042bf')})
```

Signify that index are created and record is getting removed.

so how come mongo is caching the query is there any way from mongoid to clear mongo cache 
If mongo is caching the query

Comment: just a note restarted my mongo Server but still the same problem .Now this dont look like caching what is it can anyone explain

Comment: further investigation are more shocking running PartPriceRecord.first or PartPriceRecord.find(:all).first return nil but PartPriceRecord.find(:all)[0] return a valid result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caveat: I am not a mongoid user.

> so how come mongo is caching the query

Mongo itself doesn't do any caching like that.

If you look at the queries executed on the db:

```
$ mongodb viren
> db.setProfilingLevel(0); 
> db.system.profile.drop();  
> db.setProfilingLevel(2);
```

Then execute your code, you'll see something like this in the log:

```
> db.system.profile.find()
{ "ts" : ISODate("2012-05-09T08:39:21.657Z"), "op" : "insert", "ns" : "viren.part_price_records", "millis" : 0, "client" : "127.0.0.1", "user" : "" }
{ "ts" : ISODate("2012-05-09T08:39:26.553Z"), "op" : "remove", "ns" : "viern.part_price_records", "query" : { }, "millis" : 0, "client" : "127.0.0.1", "user" : "" }
```

Looking directly at the db will allow you to know/understand exactly what queries are issued and if there is caching - where it is (it won't be in the db itself).

**However**, the *big* difference above to the query log you've shown in the question is that `.remove({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('4fa39b35edd7f4306b0042bf')})` will remove at most one object, the conditions above (`{}`) will truncate the collection.

Looking at the docs for [destroy all](http://mongoid.org/docs/persistence/standard.html#destroy_all), it runs callbacks on each deleted row - which probably means it deletes them one at a time (which with 30k rows will take a significant time). You can use [delete all](http://mongoid.org/docs/persistence/standard.html#delete_all) and it will (I assume) directly issue a query to delete all rows (`db.part_price_records.remove({})`) instead. If you need destroy callbacks, you need to investigate why your code apparently only finds one row to delete, or which callback is aborting the delete for the other existing rows.

Comment: Yes delete_all work as expected i dont know y the destory_all is not working the same although I dont have and callback either. thanks but gr8 help

Comment: I not sure whom to blame mongoid or mongodb know creating a new record is doesnt reflect in count nor can i access it through query check this https://github.com/meetme2meat/mongoid-screenshot/raw/master/Screenshot-1.png