# Rails 3 - Why does calling .first on Mongoid cursor start new QUERY

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I've been analyzing speed on my site, and I've found a problem with it. Here is my controller:

```
  before_filter :authorize
  before_filter :load_stuff

  def load_stuff
    @messages = current_user.messages.desc(:created_at).limit(5)
    @accounts = current_user.accounts.limit(5)
    @searches = current_user.searches.desc(:updated_at).where(complete: true).limit(5)
    @last_message = @messages.first.message_body if @messages.first.present?
    @last_video = @messages.first.video_id if @messages.first.present?
  end

  def index
    @message = Message.new url: @last_video, message_body: @last_message
  end
```

And this is the query list it generates:

```
Processing by PromoteController#index as HTML
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (0.7179ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=tp3_development collection=users selector={"_id"=>"5130abdfc9f2672059000005"} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.3302ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=tp3_development collection=messages selector={"$query"=>{"user_id"=>"5130abdfc9f2672059000005"}, "$orderby"=>{"created_at"=>-1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.5000ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=tp3_development collection=messages selector={"$query"=>{"user_id"=>"5130abdfc9f2672059000005"}, "$orderby"=>{"created_at"=>-1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.3879ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=tp3_development collection=messages selector={"$query"=>{"user_id"=>"5130abdfc9f2672059000005"}, "$orderby"=>{"created_at"=>-1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.3750ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=tp3_development collection=messages selector={"$query"=>{"user_id"=>"5130abdfc9f2672059000005"}, "$orderby"=>{"created_at"=>-1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.3281ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=tp3_development collection=accounts selector={"user_id"=>"5130abdfc9f2672059000005"} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=5 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.3731ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=tp3_development collection=searches selector={"$query"=>{"user_id"=>"5130abdfc9f2672059000005", "complete"=>true}, "$orderby"=>{"updated_at"=>-1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=5 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (3.7348ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=tp3_development command={:count=>"messages", :query=>{"user_id"=>"5130abdfc9f2672059000005"}} (0.3629ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=tp3_development collection=messages selector={"$query"=>{"user_id"=>"5130abdfc9f2672059000005"}, "$orderby"=>{"created_at"=>-1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=5 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.3257ms)
  Rendered promote/index.html.erb within layouts/application (7.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 11.3ms)
```

Now If I remove these 2 lines:

```
@last_message = @messages.first.message_body if @messages.first.present?
@last_video = @messages.first.video_id if @messages.first.present?
```

Than number of queries drops to this:

```
Processing by PromoteController#index as HTML
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (0.5271ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=tp3_development collection=users selector={"_id"=>"5130abdfc9f2672059000005"} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.2854ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=tp3_development collection=accounts selector={"user_id"=>"5130abdfc9f2672059000005"} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=5 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.5162ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=tp3_development collection=searches selector={"$query"=>{"user_id"=>"5130abdfc9f2672059000005", "complete"=>true}, "$orderby"=>{"updated_at"=>-1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=5 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (6.1519ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=tp3_development command={:count=>"messages", :query=>{"user_id"=>"5130abdfc9f2672059000005"}} (0.3920ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=tp3_development collection=messages selector={"$query"=>{"user_id"=>"5130abdfc9f2672059000005"}, "$orderby"=>{"created_at"=>-1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=5 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.2959ms)
  Rendered promote/index.html.erb within layouts/application (11.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 99ms (Views: 15.4ms)
```

So my question is, why does those 2 lines generate 4 additional queries, and how to avoid it?

Answer (score -1):

Because  **@messages** is your mongoid criteria

which means it does not fire the query and it build the query for you(like arel) and unlike

relational database which cache the result for the query mongodb does not cache your query

so for example assume the above

```
Does MongoDB handle caching?
Yes. MongoDB keeps all of the most recently used data in RAM. If you have created indexes for your queries and your working data set fits in RAM, MongoDB serves all queries from memory.

MongoDB does not implement a query cache: MongoDB serves all queries directly from the indexes and/or data files.
```

Straight out of Mongo documentation check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112420/mongoid-query-caching) for answer as well

for **1 query**

`@messages.first.present?`

**2 query**

`@messages.first.message_body`

**3 query**

`@messages.first.present?`

**4 query**

`@messages.first.video_id`

OMG what I have to do well to be precise you dont have to worry abt it

a) MongoDB is meant for speed like read operation.

b) As mention earlier if the mongo document if you created index from the queries there highly likely changes that the query result would be fetch from memory

**NOTE:** I know there in [this](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/extras.html#caching) caching thing in mongoid I not sure what it does because the last time I tried it wasnt working the way it was documented

Comment: Please don't write answers like they are an sms to your best friend (ur, OMG, u, etc.)

Comment: ok, so as long as I build indexes, it doesn't matter how many queries there are, as they are RAM based. Will take a look into caching. Also, -1 is not from me.

Comment: @JanNetherdrake Sorry for late reply was away Yes u are right as long as u built index it would store the recent result in memory with regards to ur other question `how much` I not completely sure how to answer this because mongodb memory mapped it file to OS and then it all up to OS to cache it and evict if it run out of memory I presume the following  [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/)  and [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/diagnostics/) would help u if u want to know in depth insight of how memory Mongo would use and other stuff