# Mongoid cache doesn't seem to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am trying to work with mongoid cahce.

First off I am not sure where to put my criteria right now it's sitting in a class variable ( feels like the wrong spot )

```
class YearDates
  include Mongoid::Document
  @@yeardates_cache =  YearDates.where(year: DateHelper.today.year).cache

  def self.current_year
    @@yeardates_cache.first
  end
```

Now i expected to only hit the mongo once when i call YearDates.current_year

However ever time I call the current_year I see in the logs:

```
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=unit_test collection=year_dates selector={"$query"=>{"year"=>2013}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to [mongoid query caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112420/mongoid-query-caching)
"rehevkor5 Jul 31 at 23:13" <- read this comment at the bottom !